# Representation of algebra v.s. modules over algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I got confused when dealing with these two situations. If we consider the same algebra, and also require the module itself is a real/complex vector space,

1. Are they equivalent definitions?
2. How much are the two theory equivalent? e.g. Is simple module the same as irreducible representation?

Comment: What sort of algebra is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a representation and a module are the same thing (e.g. of a group algebra), the theory is equivalent, and irreducible representations are the same thing as simple modules.

I don't know exactly what is responsible for the difference in terminology but it likely comes from different communities of researchers working in representation theory and (non)commutative algebra or similar, respectively. I don't think it was understood initially that representations of e.g. finite groups could be subsumed into module theory (which did not yet exist), and not all representation theories can, e.g. representations of [algebraic groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_group) are [comodules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comodule) rather than modules.

Comment: Nice and short but still complete answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!